# Peek into Conn without reading in go

Tags: sockets, networking, go, peek

I have a server `net.Conn`, and I'd like to peek into it before reading out bytes, to check if it's a plain text protocol the client is trying to use, or SSL/TLS.

Checking http://golang.org/pkg/net/, it seems the `Conn` interface does not have anything like that. I know I could use an `iobuf.Reader`, but I'd like to get a TLS Conn via `tls.Conn(conn, config)` if it turns out the client is using SSL/TLS, and `bufio.Reader` would read from the original `Conn`, thus the handshake in `tls.Conn` would fail.

So is there any way to peek into a `Conn` in Go (something like `MSG_PEEK` in C/C++ sockets)? Or, to create a `tls.Conn` after I had read out the first few bytes from the underlying `Conn`?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You're very close to a solution - the only thing you got wrong was reading from the `Conn` itself first. You are right that `bufio.Reader`'s `Peek` method is the way to go. The trick is to make the buffered reader first and call `Peek` on the buffered reader rather than reading from the original `Conn`. Here's a `bufferedConn` type that will do what you need:

```
type bufferedConn struct {
    r        *bufio.Reader
    net.Conn // So that most methods are embedded
}

func newBufferedConn(c net.Conn) bufferedConn {
    return bufferedConn{bufio.NewReader(c), c}
}

func newBufferedConnSize(c net.Conn, n int) bufferedConn {
    return bufferedConn{bufio.NewReaderSize(c, n), c}
}

func (b bufferedConn) Peek(n int) ([]byte, error) {
    return b.r.Peek(n)
}

func (b bufferedConn) Read(p []byte) (int, error) {
    return b.r.Read(p)
}
```

What this does is allow you to access all of the normal `net.Conn` methods (by embedding the `net.Conn` - you could also write wrapper functions, but this is a lot easier and cleaner), and additionally provide access to the `bufferedReader`'s `Peek` and `Read` methods (it's important that `Read` be called on the `bufferedReader`, not directly on the `net.Conn` because `Peek` stores data in a buffer, so subsequent calls to `Read` need to be able to first read any data out of this buffer before falling back to the underlying `net.Conn`).

The `newBufferedConnSize` function is probably unnecessary given that the current default buffer size is 4096 bytes, but technically if you're going to rely on being able to call `Peek` with a given size and not have it return an error (specifically [`ErrBufferFull`](http://golang.org/pkg/bufio/#pkg-variables)), you should set it explicitly to a size that's at least as big as the number of bytes you intend to peek.

Check it out on the [Go Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/XPhIPqpMcW).

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar situation I was working with. What we did is implement a two simple C functions - however - I think a golang implementation is perhaps better.

```c
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>

buffered readders
ssize_t peek_socket_data(int socket_fd, void *buffer, size_t length) {
    return recv(socket_fd, buffer, length, MSG_PEEK);
}

ssize_t available_socket_data(int socket_fd) {
    int bytes_available;
    if (ioctl(socket_fd, FIONREAD, &bytes_available) == -1) {
        return -1;
    }
    return bytes_available;
}
```

And then the go function:

```golang
// CPeekSocketData retrieves everything available on the socket without removing it.
func CPeekSocketData(fd int) ([]byte, error) {
    // First, get the amount of available data
    available := C.available_socket_data(C.int(fd))
    if available == -1 {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("error determining available data on socket")
    }
    if available == 0 {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("no data available on socket")

        // return []byte{}, nil // No data available
    }

    // Allocate buffer for the available data
    buffer := make([]byte, available)

    // Peek at the data
    n, err := C.peek_socket_data(C.int(fd), unsafe.Pointer(&buffer[0]), C.size_t(available))
    if n == -1 {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("error peeking at socket data: %v", err)
    }

    return buffer[:n], nil
}
```

I suggest you use a go-native implementation if it works